# Correctly converting Chrome timestamp to date using python

Tags: python, sqlite, google-chrome, python-3.x, timestamp

I scraped chrome history using python. `late_visit_time` row is giving a timestamp, something like this - `13107300761977770`. When I converted it to date using following code:

> ```
> timestamp = 13107300761977770
> value = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
> ```

I got following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
> value = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
> ```

I even changed my code to this:

> ```
> timestamp = 13107300761977770/1e3
> value = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
> ```

but I got the same error.

After that, to change timestamp's size to I did this:

> ```
> timestamp = 13107300761977770/1e7
> value = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
> print(value)
> ```

It gave me `2011-07-15 17:11:16.197777` as a result which was wrong because the history which I used as my sample data was collected in 2016 only.
**What should be the possible solution to my problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime

timestamp = 13107300761977770
value = datetime.datetime(1601, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=timestamp)
print(value)
```